# Probability distribution and expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Okay so there is this card game for two players with rules as follows: 
-each player is dealt a card
-if either card is a spade, the player wins
-is neither is a spade or both are spades, the cards are replaced and reshuffled and cards are dealt again. Play continues for up to 7 deals. 
If neither player wins by a spade on 7th deal, the player with the higher card wins; but if the cards are of equal rank, the player with the higher suit wins (S-H-D-C). The random variable D is the number of deals in the game. I want to know how to construct a probability distribution for this random variable and find the expected value of D. Any ideas?

Comment: This is assuming the standard "deck of cards" with $13$ ranks and $4$ suits, correct?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Can you compute the probability that $D=1$?

Comment: Yeah, @lulu , I know that while constructing the probability distribution, D will be equal to 1 to 7 so 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, but how do i find the probability of D for each deal?

Comment: Well, try.  What needs to happen in order for $D$ to be $1$?  As a quick approximation, the probability that $A$ wins on the first round is about $\frac 14\times \frac 34$.  Can you see why that is only an approximation (albeit a pretty good one)?

Comment: But the correct answer for probability of D after the first deal is 0.3823

Comment: If you know the answer, then you don't need help.  My approximation is for the probability that player  $A$ wins.  That is half the probability that $D=1$, as player $B$ might also win so the approximation yields $2\times \frac 14\times \frac 34=.375$ which is a decent, but not exact, approximation to your .3823

Comment: With your approximation, can you know the probability at deals 1, 2, 3,4 5, 6 and 7 ? Because with these probabilities i can add them up and get the expected value.

Comment: Try to understand $D=1$ first.  Work out why the approximation is sensible and that should tell you how to do it exactly.  Once you understand that case completely, it will be easy to finish the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you did D=1 where probability is 1/4 *3/4. Is it because to win then one out of 4 spades have to be obtained?